# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 after updating FLUTTER from Version 1 to 2.9 (channel beta)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

After pausing on my app project (which is running on iOS and Android mobiles and tablets) for about 6 month I now updated android studio (including Flutter, etc.) for further development of my app.
The android studio update worked without problems for the iOS simulator.
But when I tried to run it using an Android Emulator I now get a lot of errors:

```
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
```

...
and the list of errors ends with:

```
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/appname/android/build.gradle:
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

If I am checking my running android studio for updates (IDE or plugin), I get the message, that there are no new updates for android studio IDE or plugins
My first question: Does that include the Kotlin updates?

My general question: How do I get the Android device emulator running (the iOS simulator runs without problems for my flutter app project) ?

Answer (score 0):

... I solved it by myself:
in Android Studio (current version):
1 ) -> update gradle to version 1.5.10
2 ) -> update SDK version to #31 (download via tools -> SDK manager)
now: iOS and android simulators are working well
(one problem was the plugin audioplayers)

Best, Bernd